# Why I got an incomplete type error and how to solve it?

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

This is a code a got for now but it doesnt compile due to an incomplete variable type container::iterator error. The class and the iterator are still pretty simple since I am trying to figure out how to organise my code.

```
template <typename T> class container {
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using pointer           = T*;
    using const_pointer     = const T*;
public:
    class iterator;
    container (size_type n=0):  data {n>0 ? new T[n]:nullptr}, size {n>0 ? n:0}{};
    container (iterator begin, iterator end){};
    ~container (){ delete[] data; };
private:
    pointer     data;
    size_type   size;
};

template <typename T> class container<T>::iterator {
public:
    iterator (pointer p): current {p} {};
    iterator& operator++ (){ current++; return *this; };
    iterator& operator-- (){ current--; return *this; };
    reference operator* (){ return *current; };
    bool operator== (const iterator& b) const { return current == b.current; };
    bool operator!= (const iterator& b) const { return current != b.current; };
private:
    pointer current;
};
```

I would like to keep the iterator definition out of the container class if possible. Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to keep the iterator definition out of the container class if possible.

It isn't, because the arguments for `container`'s member functions cannot be properly analysed without a definition for their type.

Move it inline.

Answer (score 2):

```
container (iterator begin, iterator end){};
```

That uses `iterator` but at that point in the code there's no definition of `iterator`, only a declaration.  You'll need to define the structure of your iterator before you can even declare this constructor.

You *could* alter this constructor to take references.  Then you can *declare* it within your class but then define it below the definition for iterator.  IMO this isn't the best way to go, but it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is the line causing the problem. I wondered if there is a 'regular' workaround for that. It seems it isnt except an inline definition.